# What command can structure and layout code in Atom?

Tags: html, atom-editor

I copied code and pasted it in Atom (text editor), but it is all wrapped and very unclear to understand now. I'm looking for a command that unwraps the code and structures it automatically, instead of manually adding tabs and spaces.

[example of what I mean with wrapped text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YBJRS.png)

Answer (score 0):

I replaced all the ">" with "> \n", which makes it a bit more clear already, but still not perfect

Answer (score 0):

Use [Atom-Beautify](https://atom.io/packages/atom-beautify). Here's their demo:

Before:

[image: screenshot of Atom showing unformatted HTML]

After:

[image: screenshot of Atom showing nicely formatted HTML]